# Como iterar un JSON de forma correcta en Laravel?

Tags: laravel, json, mongodb, laravel-blade

Estoy comenzando a utilizar Mongo con Laravel. He conseguido realizar la conexion y ejecutar las primeras consultas agregadas.
La duda que tengo ahora es recorrer los resultados con **foreach** en la plantilla de **blade**.

El siguiente archivo de json lo recorro sin problemas

```
$json = '{
   "tag":{
      "title":"titulo"      
   }
}';

$data = json_decode($json);

return view('dashboard.book.index', compact('data'));
```

En el Blade:

```
  @foreach($data as $item)
      {{ $item->title }}
      <br/>
  @endforeach
```

Ahora bien, como le hago para recorrer el siguiente archivo mas complejo?:

```
$json2 = '{
  "tag":{
     "title": {
         "t1": "superman,
         "t2": "batman"
       }        
}';
```

No se como acceder al **t1** o **t2** del **title**.

He intentado lo siguiente pero sin exito.

```
@foreach($data as $item)
      {{$item->title->t1}}      
       <br/>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

Pues yo utilizo Alpine.js en laravel, y es bastante sencillo hacerlo con Alpine, pero en general tienes que conseguir la forma de ubicar las propiedades en los elementos HTML através de funciones JS tipo InnerHTML. Tengo entendido que la sintaxis de blade imprimirá las variables que le pases a la vista desde el controlador, y en este caso veo que quieres imprimir variables de un objeto JSON por lo tanto te sugiero probar haciendo una función donde recorras el JSON con un bucle, y extraigas los valores de los objetos para ubicarlos en los elementos HTML que quieras.